# Update column values in a table in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with numbers in a field `COL_1`. I want to replace values with `COL_1 * 2` (double all the values). I'm not sure the correct way to do this.

Is the following code correct?

```sql
update MY_TABLE
  set COL_1 = COL_1 * 2
;
```

**Note:** Feel free to assume this transformation interacts with any self-referential field.

*If this were python code, you could execute using the following:*

```py
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'] * 2
```

Comment: More context needed: Table definition? Sample JSON? Etc

Comment: Feel free to assume that it's any self-referential value @FelipeHoffa. EX: `col_1 = int` and I want to replace `col_1` with a value that's double itself. (In pandas this would be `df['col_1'] = 2 * df['col_1']`

Comment: how does your json look like?

Comment: Share what is expected with some sample json data and expected output.

Comment: The value of my JSON is irrelevant. The operation is any self-referential transformation.

Comment: ybressler - please listen to what @eshirvana, @ anand, and me are saying — we want to help you, but you need to give us concrete examples with JSON

Comment: ybressler  - There are people to help but question should be precise to get reasonable answer. Otherwise it will end up throwing random answers which goes in infinite loop for no reason.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help and suggestions. I just modified my Q: hopefully is more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it really depends on how your json look like but generally the syntax would be like this :

```
UPDATE tablename
SET DATA = OBJECT_INSERT(DATA, col_1, DATA:col_1::int * 2) 
WHERE <your condition>;
```

otherwise if you just want to a column just simple update:

```
update MY_TABLE
set COL_1 = COL_1 * 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated the Q to be a bit more precise. (I think the JSON aspect was throwing people off)

Comment: @ybressler_simon well, then your query is correct , just multiply the value by 2 and set it back

Comment: Got it. Let's say this operation encounters an error (a value is null). I imagine it'll be all or nothing, right?

Comment: @ybressler_simon NULL value * 2 is still NULL , so it won't produce any error , unless you have a non digit only value in that column ( which I assume its impossible if that column data typ is a numeric (of any type))